# Product stock quantity is reducing automatically before shipment

Tags: magento2, product, stock, inventory

How the product stock quantity is decreasing automatically in magento2 before shipment(not saleable quantity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine the quantity that is decreased is the **Salable quantity**. From the frontend, it appears as if the quantity has been decreased. But in reality MSI only reserves the items that are ordered.

**The flow is as follows:**

- When your order is placed in Magento 2, the salable quantity is decreased.

--> Magento removes the quantity for the items in the order (these have become reserved)

- When the shipment is created, the quantity is decreased. This is something we are used to.

See below in the screenshot, we can see 2 columns for the quantity. Hope this is the problem you're having, good luck

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked this but its not resolved
 Is there any chance to reduce the normalquantity before shipment?

Comment: yes, but not OOTB